# Search bar to search through TextViews

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have made an application that has several insurance companies in a `RelativeLayout` within a `ScrollView`. Each Insurance company is within a `LinerarLayout`. Is it possible to have a search bar that would search through the TextViews and return only the `TextView` that has been searched for.

My Code is as fallows

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:background="@drawable/bg"
        tools:context="saveourcar.soc.Insurance">
        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
            android:layout_width="580dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout01"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
        android:layout_width="580dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="20dip"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
        android:textSize="27dp"
        android:text="@string/chooseinsurance"/>
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/list_item9"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="62dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/list_item"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:background="#26BFDA" >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="33dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                android:src="@drawable/onetwothree" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/TextView08"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="21sp"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:text="@string/oneTwoThree"/>
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="51dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:onClick="onClick123Arrow"
                android:src="@drawable/nextarrow" />

            <!-- Put line under text -->


        </LinearLayout>
        <View
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:background="#c0c0c0" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/list_item10"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="62dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/list_item"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:background="#26BFDA" >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="33dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                android:src="@drawable/acorn" />


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/TextView10"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="21sp"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:text="@string/acorn"/>
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="51dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:onClick="onClickAcornArrow"
                android:src="@drawable/nextarrow" />



        </LinearLayout>
        <View
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:background="#c0c0c0" />


        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/list_item11"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="62dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/list_item"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:background="#26BFDA" >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="33dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                android:src="@drawable/admiral" />


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/TextView11"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="21sp"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:text="@string/admiral"/>
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="51dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:onClick="onClickAdmiralArrow"
                android:src="@drawable/nextarrow" />



        </LinearLayout>
        <View
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:background="#c0c0c0" />

</RelativeLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Each insurance company is directly beneath the other split by a `View`. This is only a snippet of my code. This picture is what my Insurance activity currently looks like.

[image]

Comment: why not use a listview with filter

Comment: @ankitagrawal I'm new to android studio and yes I agree in hindsight that a listView would have been the better option but I have already it done in TextViews.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you want to accomplish but I think there is a simpler solution to you problem.

[Library that might help you a lot](https://github.com/Wrdlbrnft/Searchable-RecyclerView-Demo)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

Add a edittext at the top of your activity as a searchbar and

```
EditText searchedittext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search_layoutEditText);

        String edittxt = searchedittext.getText().toString();
        if(edittxt.isEmpty()){

                //display a dialog or toast saying no results found
               }else{
                          //write the condition to display the textviews matching the searched insurance company

      ◆                 }
```

**and as ankitagarwal said it would be easy using a list view**

Comment: Thanks for replying to me. Yes I agree in hindsight that a listView would have been the better option but I have already it done in TextViews. I'm new with Android and I'm wondering what condition I would write to display the textviews matching the searched insurance company

Comment: @CraigGallagher that is why you are not able to use search since if you have used a listview via an adapter then you can add code in adapter class to filter the listview using search .... see some tutorials of using listview since the method  you are following is not right,,,happy coding